# AIR for iOS: Mouse Clicks do not work on one frame?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

So I have a really weird error at the moment. I'm just about ready to deploy my app to the App Store (having already had several debug versions running as expected on my iPhone), but all of a sudden, mouse clicks do not appear to work on one single frame.

They run as expected in Flash CS6 Pro's iPhone Simulator (ADL).

The events are set up in the same way across the few frames and there should not be an issue at all. I have not changed the event listeners or functions since updating other elements of program.

It is also worth noting that the animation for MOUSE_DOWN on these buttons is working correctly.

I have tried the following to fix the problem, but to no avail:

- Add the event listeners directly to each button
- Have one event listener handling every single button
- Add that single event listener to the stage
- Use the MOUSE_UP event instead of MouseEvent.CLICK

Prompt help would be greatly appreciated as I am hoping to deploy this app to have it reviewed ASAP. Also, simply because it is confusing the heck out of me..

Thanks a lot in advance,
Harry.

Comment: 1. How about listening to TouchEvent ?   2. Do you listen on control with full transparent background ? Please post some code

Comment: Don't worry, problem has been solved. It turns out that Flash automatically added an import statement for flash.events.MouseEvent when I added a separate button, and this conflict caused MouseEvents to no longer work.

Comment: It makes plenty of sense. When I added a line of code to listen for a Mouse
C

Answer (score -1):

Having a second import for flash.events.MouseEvent caused a conflict which stopped mouse clicks from working (the import statement was called again on this specific frame, hence why other frames worked as expected but this one didn't).